# Generar Multiple LineChart ChartJS desde un Objeto

Tags: javascript, json, angular, chart.js, javascript-objeto

de antemano muchas gracias.

Estoy tratando de cargar un ChartLine con Chartjs en Angular, la propiedades del Chart hasta donde logre entender deben ser array, en **labels** y en el **data** del **datasets**, mi problema es que la información que viene del servidor es un objeto como este:

```
{
 "2021": [
     {
         "estado": "APROBADA",
         "cantidad": "5582"
     },
     {
         "estado": "INCONS",
         "cantidad": "1"
     },
     {
         "estado": "PENDIENTE",
         "cantidad": "27"
     },
     {
         "estado": "RECHAZADA",
         "cantidad": "146"
     }
 ],
 "2022": [
     {
         "estado": "APROBADA",
         "cantidad": "4065"
     },
     {
         "estado": "INCONS",
         "cantidad": "1"
     },
     {
         "estado": "PENDIENTE",
         "cantidad": "275"
     },
     {
         "estado": "RECHAZADA",
         "cantidad": "179"
     }
 ]
}
```

Como podría generar un array de ese objeto con los estados para usarlos como **labels** y la cantidad para generar ambos lineCharts?

La data la estoy recibiendo en Angular por socket:

```
    this.socket.web().subscribe( (data:any) => {
      this.web = data;

    // Recorrer Objeto ¿como?
      for (const key in this.web) {
        //console.log(key);
        for (const data in this.web[key]) {

          this.lblWeb = Object.keys(this.groupArrayOfObjects(this.web[key],"estado"));
          this.dataWeb = Object.keys(this.groupArrayOfObjects(this.web[key],"cantidad"));

        }
      }

    let dataVar = {
        labels: this.lblWeb,
        datasets: [{
            label: this.anioAlta,
            backgroundColor: "rgb(115 185 243 / 65%)",
            borderColor: "#007ee7",
            borderWidth: 1,
            fill: false,
            data: this.dataWeb
        }]
     };


      if(this.chartjs){
        this.chartjs.destroy();
      }

      this.chartjs = new Chart('myChart', {
        type: 'line',
        data: dataVar,
        options: {
            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            },
            plugins:{
              legend:{
                display:true,
                position: 'top',
                labels: {
                  color: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
                }
              }
            }            
        }
      });
      

    });
```

Solo he logrado colocar los labels con la función **groupArrayOfObjects**

```
     groupArrayOfObjects(list:any, key:any) {
        return list.reduce((rv:any, x:any) => {
          (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
          return rv;
        }, {});
     };
```

De momento no logro asociar la data con los labels ya que el grafico se genera pero no asociando al label y tampoco mostrar ambas lineChart. Perdón si me extendí, pero he probado de todo.

Gracias y espero puedan echarme una mano.

Saludos

Comment: Hola, pudieras adjuntar una imagen de como quieres que quede tu grafica, lo primero es definir que grafico muestra correctamente la información que quieres mostrar, en mi caso particular no haría una `lineChart` con esos datos, sino un `radarChart`  https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/other-charts/radar.html

Comment: @RodolfoBarbeitoRodriguez gracias por responder, básicamente lo que tengo en mente hacer es en un lineChart donde cada año sea una linea, por ejemplo linea verde año 2021, linea roja año 2022, voy a probar con el radarChart, pero mi problema reside en la iteración, puedo iterar pero no se como incluir esa iteración dentro de chartjs, probablemente sea recorrer con un FOR IN e ir añadiendo las propiedades que necesito, de momento sigo investigando.

Answer (score 1):

te tengo una propuesta, según los datos que te envía el `backend` de esta forma el grafico se muestra, creo que puedes optimizar el codigo.

Este fue mi `component.ts`

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef,  ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-linear',
  templateUrl: './linear.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./linear.component.css']
})
export class LinearComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('myChart') chart!: ElementRef;
  grafico: any

  labels:string[]=[]
  serie1:number[]=[]
  serie2:number[]=[]

  datos={
          "2021": [
        {
          "estado": "APROBADA",
          "cantidad": "5582"
        },
        {
          "estado": "INCONS",
          "cantidad": "1"
        },
        {
          "estado": "PENDIENTE",
          "cantidad": "27"
        },
        {
          "estado": "RECHAZADA",
          "cantidad": "146"
        }
      ],
      "2022": [
        {
          "estado": "APROBADA",
          "cantidad": "4065"
        },
        {
          "estado": "INCONS",
          "cantidad": "1"
        },
        {
          "estado": "PENDIENTE",
          "cantidad": "275"
        },
        {
          "estado": "RECHAZADA",
          "cantidad": "179"
        }
      ]

  }
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

this.datos["2021"].forEach(l=>{
  this.labels.push(l.estado)
  this.serie1.push(+l.cantidad)
})
this.datos["2022"].forEach(l=>{
  this.serie2.push(+l.cantidad)
})
 console.log(Object.keys(this.datos)[0])
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {

    this.grafico = new Chart(this.chart.nativeElement,{
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels:this.labels,
        datasets: [{
          label: Object.keys(this.datos)[0],
          data: this.serie1,
          fill: false,
          borderColor: 'rgb(44,119,2)',
          backgroundColor: 'rgb(44,119,2)',
          tension: 0.1
        },
          {
            label: Object.keys(this.datos)[1],
            data: this.serie2,
            fill: false,
            borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
            tension: 0.1
          }]
      }
    })
  }

}
```

y asi mi `component.html`

```
<div>
  <canvas #myChart ></canvas>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @RodolfoBarbeitoRodriguez gracias por tu respuesta, no había tenido tiempo de revisarlo, de momento me funciona, pero debo hacerlo mas dinámico, ya que cuando llegue el año 2023 debo tomar ese valor dinámicamente. Gracias

Comment: El backend lo estas programando tu mismo? si la respuesta es si, creo que seria muy bueno cambiar un poco la estructura del objeto, de manera que el año, sea un valor y no una llave, algo asi por ejemplo: `{año:"2021",datos:[{"estado": "APROBADA", "cantidad": "5582"}]}`